# Coq: a vicious circle with two identical subgoals

Tags: coq, propositional-calculus

Sorry for overcomplicated example. I have

```
Lemma test : forall x y z : Prop,
 (
     (((x → (y ∨ z)) → (x ∨ y)) ↔ (x ∨ y))
   ∧ (((y → (x ∨ z)) → (x ∨ y)) ↔ (x ∨ y))
   ∧  ((y → (x ∨ z)) → (x ∨ (x → (y ∨ z))))
   ∧  ((x → (y ∨ z)) → (y ∨ (y → (x ∨ z))))
  )  → ((x → (y ∨ z)) → (y ∨ z)).
```

Doing

```
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H.
  destruct H1.
  destruct H2.
  pose proof (H3 H0).
```

gives

```
1 goal
x, y, z : Prop
H : ((x → y ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H1 : ((y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H2 : (y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ (x → y ∨ z)
H3 : (x → y ∨ z) → y ∨ (y → x ∨ z)
H0 : x → y ∨ z
H4 : y ∨ (y → x ∨ z)
______________________________________(1/1)
y ∨ z
```

I then do `destruct H4.` and this gives

```
2 goals
x, y, z : Prop
H : ((x → y ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H1 : ((y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H2 : (y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ (x → y ∨ z)
H3 : (x → y ∨ z) → y ∨ (y → x ∨ z)
H0 : x → y ∨ z
H4 : y
______________________________________(1/2)
y ∨ z
______________________________________(2/2)
y ∨ z
```

which I already don't understand: why two identical goals??
I then do `left.` and obtain

```
2 goals
x, y, z : Prop
H : ((x → y ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H1 : ((y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H2 : (y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ (x → y ∨ z)
H3 : (x → y ∨ z) → y ∨ (y → x ∨ z)
H0 : x → y ∨ z
H4 : y
______________________________________(1/2)
y
______________________________________(2/2)
y ∨ z
```

and then `assumption.` gives

```
1 goal
x, y, z : Prop
H : ((x → y ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H1 : ((y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H2 : (y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ (x → y ∨ z)
H3 : (x → y ∨ z) → y ∨ (y → x ∨ z)
H0 : x → y ∨ z
H4 : y → x ∨ z
______________________________________(1/1)
y ∨ z
```

Then doing

```
pose proof (H3 H0).
destruct H5.
left.
assumption.
```

introduces two identical goals again, and brings me to

```
1 goal
x, y, z : Prop
H : ((x → y ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H1 : ((y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ y) ↔ x ∨ y
H2 : (y → x ∨ z) → x ∨ (x → y ∨ z)
H3 : (x → y ∨ z) → y ∨ (y → x ∨ z)
H0 : x → y ∨ z
H4, H5 : y → x ∨ z
______________________________________(1/1)
y ∨ z
```

which is identical to a previous state except that I now have two identical premises `y → x ∨ z`.

I am stuck. Obviously I am doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: Can I also advertise that coq has a zulip chat: https://coq.zulipchat.com/ where you can ask any question you like and get feedback from the right people. SO is a bit isolated in some sense. The answer you have at the moment if fine, but if you have any further questions, best to ask on zulip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not only an issue about tactics or understanding how Coq works: your goal is false, as the following demonstrates.

```
Lemma test : ~ forall x y z : Prop,
 (
     (((x -> (y \/ z)) -> (x \/ y)) <-> (x \/ y))
   /\ (((y -> (x \/ z)) -> (x \/ y)) <-> (x \/ y))
   /\  ((y -> (x \/ z)) -> (x \/ (x -> (y \/ z))))
   /\  ((x -> (y \/ z)) -> (y \/ (y -> (x \/ z))))
  )  -> ((x -> (y \/ z)) -> (y \/ z)).
Proof.
  intros H.
  specialize (H False False False).
  firstorder.
Qed.
```

In other words, if `x`, `y` and `z` are taken to be `False`, then all premises to your lemma are valid, but its conclusion does not.

[Edit: How I discovered this]
I first tried the [`firstorder`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/logic.html#coq:tacn.firstorder) tactic (a decision procedure for such first-order goals) and found that it was not terminating, which got me suspicious. Then I turned to the corresponding goal boolean (using the `ssreflect`/`ssrbool` packages), where I could use case splits on `x`, `y` and `z` + computation to check whether the lemma held. Finding out that when the three of them were `false` the goal reduced to `false`, I had my counter-example, and then simply turned that back into a propositional counter-example.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me of further efforts. Still a question remains, how could Coq help to discover what you found by clever insight.

Comment: Added an edit. The conclusion is: computation/automation is wonderful if you leverage it!

Comment: Wonderful addition! Now I simply *have* to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Let us start with your first question. Actually, the two goals that were generated after `destruct` are *not* the same. Their conclusions are indeed both `y \/ z`, but their premises differ: the first one has `H4 : y`, while the second one has `H4 : y -> x \/ z`. More generally, if you have a goal of the form

```
(* ... *)
H : A \/ B
------------
 C
```

and you do `destruct H as [H1 | H2].`, you generate the subgoals

```
(* ... *)
H1 : A
-----------
  C
```

and

```
(* ... *)
H2 : B
------------
  C
```

with identical conclusions.

As for your second question, the issue is probably that you calling `pose proof (H3 H0)` twice. If you go through your script, you will notice that the hypotheses introduced by that tactic are the same on both calls: `y \/ (y -> x \/ z)`. I suspect that you should have `H2 H4` on the second call instead of `H3 H0`, though I haven't checked.

A final comment: you should letting Coq pick up the names of hypotheses for you, as this leads to unmaintainable proof scripts (see [here](http://poleiro.info/posts/2013-11-17-automatic-naming-considered-harmful.html)). Whenever possible, you should use forms such as `destruct H as [H1 | H2]` instead of `destruct H`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I learned something important from your answer but I still do not understand something essential: how do I keep track of which subgoals correspond to which premises? All I see is a list of premises and a list of subgoals, and I cannot say which premises belong to them.

Comment: As for your suggestion - I do not see how `pose proof (H2 H4)` would help at that point, since it would give `x \/ (x -> y \/ z)`, while by then I already have `x -> y \/ z`.

Comment: On the afterthought - but I now realize I also have to agree that doing `pose proof (H3 H0)` at that point is equally useless by the same reason I said: it gives `y \/ (y -> x \/ z)` while I already have `y -> x \/ z`

Comment: The list of hypothesis only applies to the first goal. If you type `admit`, the first goal will be placed momentarily on hold, and the second goal will come into focus. At this point the hypothesis match the second goal. I guess this can be confusing. You should look into [using bullets to manage your goals](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/proof-mode.html#bullets).

Comment: @ana-borges Aha thanks a lot, this is very useful!

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Oh, I see! Yeah, `H2 H4` might not be the way to go, then... I am afraid I don't have a good enough intuition to see easily how to proceed here. :/